# Can't update record

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm trying to sync three scripts together to get cross domain profile editing working. The scripts are WordPress, BuddyPress, & JamRoom.

The code I'm using go to the test domain, get the profile's information from a php call that returns JSON, and then the JSON can be pushed to the WordPress/BuddyPress database.

The only problem is that I'm a front end developer wearing a backend's hat, so I'm learning as I go.

How can I check to see if the user_id already has entries under field_id (value 1 & 2) that have filled in values? And if that exists, simply update the entries. If it doesn't exist, simply create them.

Code I'm working with
http://pastie.org/private/zivzakqyhzcbn3wkdfa6w

Columns I'm working with

```
id,field_id,user_id,"value","last_updated"
```

1,1,1,"admin","2011-03-07 00:35:52"
9,1,2,"YouRock","2011-03-07 01:11:32"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **id** is key, use a [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)-statement

Comment: No, but you may create a key of it.